# CSS Position - how make animate boxes?

Tags: html, css

I have "green" DIV. This DIV have "yellow" DIV with animate (scaleX, scaleY). I want make pink and blue box (with green DIV) and animate like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z819R.jpg

But I can not use the position so that everything does not crumbled :-/

This is my code: jsfiddle.net/ KxM68/24/

Comment: This is my animate: http://jsfiddle.net/KxM68/24/

Answer (score 1):

Just add two boxes. You can either set position:absolute or use margins

Here's one solution with margins http://jsfiddle.net/bxrMA/

CSS:

```
.pinkbox {
    background-color: pink;
    float:left;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
.bluebox {
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

And the HTML with the added divs

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 120px; background-color: green; margin: 10px 0 0 10px; padding: 80px 0 0 30px;">
    <div class="element-animation">box</div>
    <div class="pinkbox"></div>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
</div>
```